# Eclipse formatter not applying

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, formatter

I'm using Eclipse ADT 23. 
On save action I'have disabled format code. But it still gets formatted on save.
Also the applied format is not the custom one I set in Code Style -> Formatter

Comment: So you're saying you have everything disabled in the `Save Actions` preference page?

Comment: In Java -> Editor -> Save Action all is disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had specified settings for the project.

Now I have the problem that I disable formatter and save actions for specific project, but when I restart the ADT they are on again. Very annoying eclipse, can't wait for the Studio...